# AutoComplete - PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, autocomplete, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

How to add horizontal scroll to primeNg AutoComplete component when it exceeds certain width? Tried

```
overflow: auto;
```

but it only adds vertical scrolling.

```
.p-autocomplete-panel {
   max-width: 15vw;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use panelStyleClass to add a class for the panel and using ::ng-deep to style this

```
<p-autoComplete [panelStyleClass]="'custom-panel-class'"></p-autoComplete>
```

In css file

```
::ng-deep .custom-panel-class {
   max-width: 15vw;
   min-width: auto !important; 
}

// horizontal scroll 
::ng-deep .custom-panel-class .p-autocomplete-items {
    width: fit-content;
}
```